# Why apache redirects if my index page is .php on DigitalOcean VPS?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

I have an strange bug on my droplet on DigitalOcean vps.

I have set up all virtual hosts and config. I have my website located in two folders:

1 - /var/www/mysite.com/public_html 
2 - /var/www/html/mysite

I have created a etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com.conf with the following config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@mysite.com
ServerName mysite.com
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/public_html/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

My ip is 111.111.111.111
So, when I go to mysite.com in my browser, instead of running index.php in /var/www/mysite.com/public_html folder it get redirected to my IP address and runs index.html file in /var/www/html folder.

If I put absolutely another index.html file in my /var/www/mysite.com/public_html and run it, it work perfectly.

I though that there was some problem with PHP. But I have a copy of my website in  /var/www/html/mysite folder. So when I go to 111.111.111.111/mysite it runs the index.php file and the site works perfectly.

So, what is up with apache? Where is the problem?

Comment: Did you do `a2ensite mysite.conf`? Just placing the file in sites-available doesn't make the config active. Also, after enabling the config you need to do `apache2ctl reload` to actually load the config.

Comment: @favoretti I did both, if I havn't then it would not work with index.html file :( . I did everything exactly like in this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts .

Comment: What's the default `ServerName` directive in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`? Is it different from `mysite.com`, i.e. from the one in your vhost? (Sorry for asking stupid questions, just trying to filter out the obvious)

Comment: And what does `index.php` do? Are there any redirects in there? Stuff like `header()` or anything alike?

Comment: @favoretti ServerName is not set in 000-default.conf, and index.php does not have anything special. It is the entering point of the CMS code (just bunch of require(), define, etc....)

Comment: Try setting up a decisive distinctive ServerName in the default as well. It might act as a catch-all now. `sudo apache2ctl -S` should show you.

Comment: @favoretti didn't help :(

Comment: Let's try from the other side. Does your CMS have any settings regarding it's base URL? If so, what is it set to?

Comment: @favoretti yes, it is in config.php and now the problem was solved, so embarassing that I have create a whole question just because of trivial problem :(

Comment: Hehe, great you found it :)

Comment: @favoretti because I am a bad in configuring webservers, I didn't know how to read the logs on redirecting as you suggested above and forgot about rechecking the config files :( It is great that now it works.